# ¿Cómo eliminar una instancia de clase de una lista en?

Tags: python

Tengo un código que hace el registro de productos, pero debo dar la opción de eliminar uno de esos registros. he intentado con del, pero no funciona. Los registros se guardan en una lista a partir de los atributos de una clase, también se realiza la búsqueda de los registros que comparten un mismo valor en la variable codB. hasta ese momento todo funciona, pero al llegar a la función eliminarProducto() el programa se detiene y no hay forma de comprobar si elregistro se eliminó.

a continuación el código:

```
import sys

global registro
registro = []

class Producto:
    def __init__(self, p_codB, p_nombreP, p_pesoP, p_precioMay, p_precioMen):
        self.codB = p_codB
        self.nombreP = p_nombreP
        self.pesoP = p_pesoP
        self.precioMay = p_precioMay
        self.precioMen = p_precioMen
        


def registrarProducto():
    print ("Registra los datos del nuevo producto")
    
    codB = int(input("Ingrese el código de barras: "))
    nombreP = input("Ingrese el nombre del producto: ")
    pesoP = (input("Ingrese el peso del producto: "))
    precioMay = (input("Ingrese el precio de mayoreo del producto: "))
    precioMen = (input("Ingrese el precio de menudeo del producto: "))
    


    registro.append(Producto(codB, nombreP, pesoP, precioMay, precioMen))
    return("Producto agregado exitosamente")
```

**En la linea de código siguiente defino la función, pero cuando la ejecuto el programa se detiene. La idea es que se elimine solo uno de los registros aunque compartan el mismo valor en la variable codB**
*he intentado muchas formas, pero ninguna me funciona.

```
def eliminarProducto():
    codigo = input("Código de barras:>")
    if codigo in registro:
        del registro[ registro.index(codigo) ]
    

def imprimirInventario():
    print("Los productos en existencia son los siguientes")

    for Producto in registro:
        
        print(Producto.codB, ", " , Producto.nombreP, ", " , Producto.pesoP, ", " , Producto.precioMay, ", " , Producto.precioMen)


def buscarProducto():
    print("Buscar un producto")
    codigo = int(input ("ingrese el código de barras: "))

    for Producto in registro:
        if Producto.codB == codigo:
            print(Producto.codB, ", " , Producto.nombreP, ", " , Producto.pesoP, ", " , Producto.precioMay, ", " , Producto.precioMen)
        product_count = sum(1 for Producto in registro if Producto.codB == codigo)
    print("Hay ", product_count, " en existencia")



def menu():
    op = 0
    salir = 4

    while op != salir:
        print("blah bla opciones")
        op = int(input("Elige opción "))

        if op == 1:
            print(registrarProducto())

        elif op == 2:
            print(imprimirInventario())

        elif op == 3:
            print(buscarProducto())

        elif op == 4:
            eliminarProducto()

menu()      
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Bienvenido Osvaldo c: Ya has intentado `registro.remove(codigo)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recuerda que la palabra reservada "del" no puede eliminar un objeto que está almacenado en una lista, en caso de que este almacenado en una variable solamente elimina la dirección de memoria del objeto almacenado en esa variable y normalmente seguirías usando el objeto que esta en la lista.

```py
def eliminarProducto():
    # Aquí te falto ponerle int, ya que al registrar el producto el código de barras es de tipo entero
    # Te recomindo declarar variables que no se repitan
    cod = int(input("Código de barras:>"))
    
    # => if codigo in registro -> Hacer este condición no tiene sentido  || seria como decir si se encuentra una yuca en un costal de papas.
    #ya que los elementos de la lista registro no son letras, enteros u otro, Los elementos de la lista son objetos de la clase producto 
    
    for codigo in registro:
        
        if cod == codigo.codB:
            print("Código de barras correcto")
            break
    
        
    if cod == codigo.codB:
        registro.remove(codigo)
        print("Producto eliminado:", codigo.nombreP)
            
    else:
        print("El código ingresado es incorrecto")
```

Comment: En realidad `del` no elimina ningún dato, solo la variable que apunta al dato (es decir, la referencia). Mientras haya otras referencias apuntando al mismo dato, el dato seguirá en memoria. Solo cuando todas las referencias hayan desaparecido, el recolector de basura de python eliminará el objeto de la memoria.